# Javascript or html - scroll to a div inside scrollable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane

I have a scrollable div (800px x 400px). Inside is 500 smaller divs (100px x 80px), so it's a long scrollable one. Every smaller div has a id. I want to scroll to a specific div when i press a button.

I have tried some like

```
$("#outerDiv").scrollTop() = $("#innerDiv").scrollTop();
```

But i don't know if scrollTop is the right method at all? (and i know i don't use it correct)

Is there any intuitive way to do this in javascript (prefered) or just plain html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You cannot assign the return value of a method to something else. Right value cannot be evaluated.

   `$("#outerDiv").scrollTop() = something` is wrong
2. What you want should be achievable by setting the enclosing container's `scrollTop` to a child element's offset to the parent.

   `$("#outerDiv").scrollTop($("#innerDiv").position().top);`

Comment: Almost working! :-D thanks. It scrolls to the bottom of the inner-div - is there a way to make it scroll to the TOP of the inner div?

Comment: It is probably related to the box model used in your inner element. In your case, try further subtract the height of the inner-div?

Answer (score 2):

Using Javascript

```
document.getElementById('outerDiv').scrollTop = document.getElementById('innerDiv').offsetTop;
```

**Scroll Top**
If you want to scroll the contents of an element, use the scrollLeft and scrollTop properties - [Link](http://help.dottoro.com/ljnvjiow.php)

**Offset Top**
The HTMLElement.offsetTop read-only property returns the distance of the current element relative to the top of the offsetParent node. [MDN -Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/452az6km/1/)

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `scrollTop()` of the outer div to the `position().top` of the inner `div`. Also your syntax for setting `scrollTop` is a little off. Try this:

```
$("#outerDiv").scrollTop($("#innerDiv").position().top);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/452az6km/)

Comment: Thanks for fast answer! It makes sense, but does not seem to work. Am i doing anything wrong here?: $("#clearButton").click(function(){
       $("#calender").scrollTop() = $("#05052015").position().top;     
    })

Comment: If i alert(), i can both alert the outer div's current scrollTop and the inner divs position (works) - but the statement does not scroll the outer div to the inner div..

Comment: Thank you - but @WawaBrother answered before you, so i have to select his as answer.. but thank you for your time :)